# UISearchBar covered by section header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a searchBar showing as part of the tableViewHeader as created in the storyboard. However I would like to hide it under some circumstances. To accomplish this, I set the tableHeaderView.frame to a height of 0. To show it again, I set the tableHeaderView.frame to its original height. When it does show it is covered by the first section header(s). Pulling down moves the search bar along with the section header.

I tried [self.searchBar sizeToFit] after it is shown without any success. I also tried [self.view layoutSubviews].

How do I keep the section title from covering the search bar? (iOS 6 and iOS 7)

Comment: You probably want to create a custom view for your header and use it with viewForHeaderInSection.

Comment: I did the custom view thing. Instead of offsetting the frame or setting the height of the frame to zero, I kept a strong reference to the custom view and when I want to hide it, I set the tableViewHeader to nil and when I want to show it, I set it to the referenced view. Works perfectly! I haven't tested it yet, but I suspect I could just set it to the searchBar view without an enclosing view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding it by setting its height to zero, you can set the table's content offset to the search bar height. This makes it basically scroll up out of view.

Something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISearchBar* searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView* table;

...

- (void) hideSearchBar
{
    self.table.contentOffset = CGPointMake( 0, self.searchBar.frame.size.height );  
}
```